# csv.Error: iterable expected trying to save a CSV file from a For

Tags: python, csv

everything good?
I need some help to save this script in CSV that reads a CSV and transforms the data through a lib. I've been racking my brain for hours and I can't figure out why I can't save the CSV file.
Can anybody help me? I am a beginner in python and I am learning the tool to use in ETL processes.

```
import csv
from user_agents import parse

with open('UserAgent.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    idUser = 0
    space = ' / '
    for line in csv_reader:
        user_agent = parse(line[0])
        idUser = idUser + 1
        with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(user_agent)
```

Comment: `writer.writerow` expects an iterable - usaually a `list` where each element in the list corresponds to a column in the csv.  Depending  what `parse` returns, you might be able to do `writer.writerow([user_agent])`.  Also, you might want to open `data.csv` in append mode (`with open('data.csv', 'a') as f:`) so that it doesn't get overwritten for each row.

Comment: Thanks! It really works. I've change to open('data.csv', 'a') as f: to append instead of overwrite, but it jumps a line in my csv every time there is a new input. What can i do to avoid this?

Comment: try `with open('data.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:`

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a true hero my fren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writer.writerow` expects an iterable. Your `user_agent` must not be an iterable.

Try

```
writer.writerow( [user_agent] )
```

instead of

```
writer.writerow(user_agent)
```

Check if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks! It really works. I've change to open('data.csv', 'a') as f: to append instead of overwrite, but it jumps a line in my csv every time there is a new input. What can i do to avoid this?

Comment: ```with open('data.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:```